# append same string to list of strings in a column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
    a   b       c
0  'd'  1  ['f', 'h']
1  'f'  2  ['u', 'v']
2  'g'  3  ['i', 'o']
```

I want to append df['a'] to each element of df['c'] column.
expected output:

```
    a   b       c          d
0  'd'  1  ['f', 'h']  ['fd', 'hd']
1  'f'  2  ['u', 'v']  ['uf', 'vf']
2  'g'  3  ['i', 'o']  ['ig', 'og']
```

I tried for loops, and an attempt at list comprehension, but it was garbage.
To avoid for loops, I have tried this vectorized approach. But did not work.

```
df['d']=df['c'].cat(df['a'],axis=0).values.tolist()
```

As always, any help, much appreciated.

Comment: That is not a correct representation of a list of strings. The strings should be enclosed in paranthesis, like `['f', 'h']`

Comment: yes. sorry for wrong representation. please find the update now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `explode` to unnest your list, then add the strings together and finally use `groupby` on the index and use `agg(list)` to get your list back:

```
ex = df.explode('c')
ex['c'] = ex['c'] + ex['a']

df['c'] = ex.groupby(ex.index)['c'].agg(list)
```

```
   a  b         c
0  d  1  [fd, hd]
1  f  2  [uf, vf]
2  g  3  [ig, og]
```